# Settings in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

(1) I want to remove the icon of settings which was created after when i make a new project with a Navigation Drawer Activity. 
(2) And also i want change the title of item to red color i an activity_main_drawer.xml.
 (3) The last one, i want also remove title of action bar.

***The screenshot of action bar:***
[image]

*The code of menu items:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="Asosiy menyu" 
             >

            <menu>
            <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
            android:title="Yoqtirganlar" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp"
            android:title="So'ngi ko'rilganlar" />

            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

***The title of navigation menu:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first question ans is remove below code from activity..

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

then after not show setting..

3. In string.xml in remove

   ```
   <string name="app_name">RafDemo</string> // here give empty no show title in actionbar.
   ```